# Compare list of elements in js lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Hi i want to compare each element of list 1 with `component.get("v.SelectedRecordProj.Id")` if there is `v.SelectedRecordProj.I`d present in list 1, dont push, if not push `v.SelectedRecordProj.Id` in list 1. Below is the sample code that i am trying.

```
    var proVal = component.get("v.proNamesList");
    var arrs =component.get("v.proNamesList");
             for (var m = 0; m < arrs.length; m++) {
                    for (var n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
                        if (arrs[m].Id != component.get("v.SelectedRecordProj.Id")) 
                        {
                            alert('push'); 
                             proVal.push(component.get("v.SelectedRecordProj"));
                        }
                      }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access an object property using: `component.get("v.SelectedRecordProj.Id");`

You have to use: `component.get("v.SelectedRecordProj").Id;`

Also, you can use the Javascript method [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some) to check if an element Id exists in your array.

Here's the right code:

```
var arrs = component.get("v.proNamesList");
var newElement = component.get("v.SelectedRecordProj");
var existsInArray = arrs.some(function (el) {
     return el.Id === newElement.Id;
});
if(existsInArray === false) { arrs.push(newElement); }
```